# How to get an animation inside a view image frame?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

I made an animation, but I want to put it in a UIImageView so that I can move it around, clear it or restart it.

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var circle: UIImageView!

// I want to make this inside the circle UIImageView or something like that. 

let ovalStartAngle = CGFloat(90.01 * M_PI/180)
let ovalEndAngle = CGFloat(90 * M_PI/180)
let ovalRect = CGRectMake(97.5, 230, 125, 125)
let ovalPath = UIBezierPath()
ovalPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(ovalRect), CGRectGetMidY(ovalRect)),
    radius: CGRectGetWidth(ovalRect) / 2,
    startAngle: ovalStartAngle,
    endAngle: ovalEndAngle, clockwise: true)
let progressLine = CAShapeLayer()
progressLine.path = ovalPath.CGPath
progressLine.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
progressLine.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
progressLine.lineWidth = 10.0
progressLine.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
self.view.layer.addSublayer(progressLine)
let animateStrokeEnd = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
animateStrokeEnd.duration = 10.0
animateStrokeEnd.fromValue = 0.0
animateStrokeEnd.toValue = 1.0
progressLine.addAnimation(animateStrokeEnd, forKey: "animate stroke end animation")
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to add the line to imageView.layer. Or you could just add/apply the animation to the actual imageView layer and have it reset and stuff there.

Comment: Well, Im kind of a new here... So I want to know how to add/apply the animation to the imageView cause I don't know how to do it... :(

Comment: It should be just like adding the animation to your progressLine. Do imageView.layer.addAnimation(...,forKey:...) I can't test it right now, but hopefully that'll help you in the right direction

Comment: thanks men! Ill try this!!

Comment: I did it...  at the circle.layer instad of the self.view and voila! but... now I can´t restarted...  any idea??

Comment: Check out this website. I'm sure it will help you find what you need: https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/